# Adding Dividers Between Drawer List Items

Tags: android, list, view, divider, drawer

I've got a navigation drawer where the style of the list items is set to R.layout.drawer_list_item.

```
mDrawerList.setAdapter ( new ArrayAdapter<String> ( this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, mDrawerTitles ) );
```

However, it seems the XML that defines the appearance of the list items can only include a single textview. I can't add a view item below the textview, and I can't add a layout. So, how do I add a divider?

List item style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="left"
android:paddingBottom="16dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="16dp"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
android:textColor="#000000" />
```

Divider:

```
 <View
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="1dp"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
```

Comment: have you tried using the `android:divider="@drawable/some_image"` xml attribute?

Comment: ahh.... to the listview!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Look at this question: [How to properly design/style a Android Navigation Drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201727/how-to-properly-design-style-a-android-navigation-drawer)

You can add these attributes to the ListView:

```
android:divider="#FFFFFF"
android:dividerHeight="1dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you Try with a xml that is your style divider.
For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:centerColor="#999999"
            android:endColor="#555555"
            android:height="1px"
            android:startColor="#555555" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

In your listview (In the XML) use this

```
<ListView
     android:id="@+id/listaFondos"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
     android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
     android:dividerHeight="1dip" >
</ListView>
```

And in your Java Code you can use this

```
private ListView YourListview;

YourListview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.YourListview);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, mDrawerTitles);
        listaFondos.setAdapter(adapter);
```

drawer_list_item is the xml with your Textview.

I hope help you.

And sorry for my english.