# How do I style the title item in Navigation menu

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-styles, textstyle

I have

```
    <item android:title="Request"> 
        <menu> 
            <item android:title="Start" /> 
        </menu>     
    </item>
```

How do I make "Request" as bold.

To style the sub item - 'Start', I've used `android:textStyle` but it doesn't work for the super/ header/category/ title item (Request).

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="Appearance">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/drawer_item</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

**Output:**
[image]

how do I style the title item ??? which style item works for it?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201727/how-to-properly-design-style-a-android-navigation-drawer)

Comment: @ELITE Nooooo.... :( I don't want to use any `FrameLayout`. I'm happy with `NavigationView` Can't it be done without custom views?